# orbot as proxy with jaunt web-scraping

Tags: java, android, proxy, jaunt-api, orbot

I am working on app (android) that is supposed to visit website & retrieve some data from there. I was thinking it would be nice to use tor so I would not leave so much info about myself.

I've completed scraping part and everything works. Problem is, i can not make proxy accessing internet. I wanted to use Orbot as proxy. I always get 405 error and text:
"this is an http connect tunnel, not a full http proxy it appears you have configured your browser to use this tor port as an http proxy this is not correct: this port is configured as connect tunnel, not an http proxy. please configure your client accordingly. you can also use https; then the client should automatically use http connect"

Code:

```
UserAgent agent = new UserAgent();
agent.setProxyHost("127.0.0.1");
agent.setProxyPort(8118);
agent.visit("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

I've tried

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8118");
```

instead of the two middle lines from previous code as well plus few other probably not smart things (: and nothing has helped.

From error text about connect tunnel and proxy I figured problem is somewhere in networking but although I searched about it, I couldn't fix it. Perhaps something in Orbot's settings?
My question is, what am I missing please? :)